# Column level security in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, permissions, security, users

Is it possible to assign column level security in SQL Server directly on a table, without using a view?

For example, for table 'tbl', if I want column 1 to be restricted for user 1, is it possible for the user to query a `select * from tbl` with the output being every other column except the restricted columns?

My understanding is it is not possible and would throw an error stating that a column is restricted.

Is there any other way?

Comment: Don't have time for a proper answer but [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2124/filtering-sql-server-columns-using-column-level-permissions/) should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Not as far as I know, but this is exactly what views are great for. Why don't you want to use views?

Comment: @zane thanks for the response, I got this question after reading through the exact same link. So it seems it is not possible.

Comment: @sqlraptor thanks for the response, yeah I understand views are good. Wanted to know if there are any other alternates other than views.

Comment: Not really recommending it, but you could use data masking to accomplish this to some degree.  It might be OK to use on a very limited basis, but I wouldn't want to do it for a lot of columns.

Comment: How about stored procedures?  You can set security level on a stored proc.

Comment: @hinkle yeah already working on data masking of columns, can I know if there are any issues with using masking for a lot of columns? Why is it not recommended?

Comment: @keith any suggestions on how can this be achieved through SP? Is there any doc or link which you would recommend?

Comment: @Venkat I would think the only major issue with a lot of data masking would be additional CPU cycles.  Just not recommended because masking is generally intended for a few sensitive columns and I don't know how aggressively it is tested.

Comment: Using stored procedures will be similar in terms of security to views. You will deny access to the base tables, and only grant execute permission for the SP. look in the docs for ownership chaining.

Comment: @sqlraptor oh okay fine, so can I conclude that the scenario which I have stated can't be achieved directly on the base table.  It is either possible using a view or a SP.